# Is using window.location a secure way to check that your script is only included on a specific site?

Tags: javascript, security, window.location

I'm building a service where customers will include a script on their site. I will bill customers based on their usage of the script (it connects to my server to use the service.), and I also have an iFrame version. Is it safe to check their window.location.host to check that the script was posted on their own website? Customers will have the option to specify multiple domains.

Comment: Well, no, they could be using a custom browser that provides false information when accessing its global properties...

Comment: Or they could just edit the script (LOL) so that it reports a false URL when communicating with your server. You gave them the source code. That code is not protected. Basically, the client-side is completely unreliable.

Comment: Well, editing the script wouldn't help them, because then users don't get the content that my app provides. Browsers not providing false hosts would be a bigger problem, because site owners can't do anything about it, and users who use the browser don't get the content.

Comment: What I meant is this: Imagine that a customer buys your script for usage on **one** domain - Domain1. But then, he also installs the script on a bunch of other domains - Domain2, Domain3, etc. However, he edits the script so that it always reports Domain1 (he hard-codes the value Domain1 instead of reading `windows.location`). So, now, the customer is using your script on multiple domains without your knowledge. As far as you can tell, the script only runs on Domain1.

Comment: Not if I store the customer's domain on my website, and the script sends the value of window.location to my server. So the comparison is not done inside the script, but securely  on m end. This tells my server that it can start sending content to the client.

Comment: But the customer can edit the script so that it doesn't send the value of window.location, but a different value. That's my point. The customer can edit the script so that it always sends the value Domain1, even if the script is on a different domain.

Comment: in that case my service doesn't receive any confirmation that the script is actually on the correct site. My script doesn't do anything useful unless it can connect to my service.

Comment: Well, the script reports that it is on Domain1. How does your server respond? How can you differentiate such a script from a script that actually is on Domain1? That's the question here. My point is that when a script sends information to the server, you can **never** trust that information (unless some sort of authentication went on, e.g. a login process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, you shouldn't, read on.

I believe that if you change `window.location` then the browser navigates to that page. Therefore, nobody would be able to change `window.location` in order to trick your script without the browser navigating to the new page.

But nothing is stopping anyone from downloading the .js file and editing it to remove your checks. (or like Sime said, they could be using a non-standard browser)

(Confirmed that this happens on Firefox)

Comment: You don't have to download the script manually or use a custom browser. Using the inspector in Chrome or Opera I can step through the Javascript code as it loads on the page and bypass any parts of it that I want to or change the values of variables.

Comment: But if you download the script, remove the check, and host the result on a different server, it won't work anymore because it won't be able to make AJAX calls to its "home" server since it now lies in a different domain. And if the end user uses Firebug or Chrome to edit the Javascript on the fly then they're only fooling themselves when they manage to make the service work on a domain where it shouldn't (or, to say this differently, such an end user might as well just recompile their web browser with cross-domain checks commented out to achieve a similar effect).

Answer (score 0):

No. All Javascript runs client-side, and as a rule you can never rely on client-side verification.